# Requesting mongo database through express only returning path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, express

I have been working on this websocket function that calls mongodb to return some data that I have stored with the 'get'.

```
const User = require('mongoose');
const express = require('express');
const cal = require('../../app/models/data.server.model.js');
const d = require('../../app/routes/data.server.routes.js');
const data = require('./data.server.controller');

module.exports = function(app) {
require('express-ws')(app);


app.ws('/', function (ws, req) {                                                    //webSocket callback function
    ws.on('message', function (msg) {
        console.log("Message received from client: %s", msg);
        if (msg == "Update" || msg == "update") {

            const calendar = app.route('/api/data').get();                 //Query mongoose, return events.

            console.log(calendar);
            ws.send("fromJSON " + JSON.stringify(calendar));

        }
    });
});
```

};

This routes using this function:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.route('/api/data')
     .get(data.list)
     .post(users.requiresLogin, data.create);
```

Which finally should call:

```
exports.list = function(req, res) {
  Data.find().sort('-created').populate('creator', 'firstName lastName fullName').exec((err, datas) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      res.status(200).json(datas);
    }
  });
};
```

And return my data.

However all I am getting in the variable 'calendar' is a JSON object with 'path'(which is the same path - 'api/data'), 'stack' & 'methods' which are empty.

I know the data is there, since I am able to access it with some AngularJS code, but I'm not too sure how to access it here. Any help would be appreciated and let me know if I'm being a bit vague anywhere. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use asynchronous method like a synchronous method. When you send WS message you actually don't have data yet.

I'm not sure if it's the best option to call route handler. I'd change the code to something like this:

```
...
// In your model static methods you can do a method that will return data
// You use arrow function, so ES6 is okay. Then you can use Promises 
// to avoid callbacks. Mongoose supports Promises by default.
// 
getData () {
    return this
        .find()
        .sort('-created')
        .populate('creator', 'firstName lastName fullName')
        .exec();
}
```

Then `list` method will look like this:

```
exports.list = (req, res) => {
    Data
        .getData()
        .then(data => res.status(200).json(data))
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send({
                message: getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        })
}
```

And for WebSockets you can call method from the model:

```
app.ws('/', function (ws, req) {                                                    //webSocket callback function
ws.on('message', function (msg) {
    console.log("Message received from client: %s", msg);
    if (msg == "Update" || msg == "update") {

        Data
           .getData()
           .then(data => {
               console.log(data);
               ws.send("fromJSON " + JSON.stringify(calendar));
           })
           .catch(/*Handle errors here*/);

    }
});
```

});

Or you can call `Data.find().sort('-created')...` directly and not wrap in into a method.

Comment: I assume it should be Data.list() in the websocket file? Thanks for this, it's pushing me in the right direction but I'm getting 'this.find() does not exist'

Comment: Data - is your model. And `list` method should be in controller.
You should add `getData` to [static methods](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics). Then `this.find` will exist.